# EF Core : Inject custom SqlExpressionFactory

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0, ef-core-8.0

Our DB contains data that can be translated. To store the data and the translation, it has two table :

- One to contains data in the default language (ex : `Product`)
- One to contains translations that is suffixed with *Translation*. (ex : `ProductTranslation`)

I develop a EF Core extension that manage translated data.
This extension replace a select from a table by a select from a subquery.

With :

```cs
context.Product
    .Where(t => t.Description.Contains('free'))
    .OrderBy(t => t.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Normaly generate this SQL :

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Description
FROM Product
WHERE Description like 'free'
OrderBy Name
```

But with the extension, that generate the SQL :

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Description
FROM (
    SELECT  Name, COALESCE(t.Name, o.Name), COALESCE(t.Description, o.Description)
    FROM Product as o
    LEFT JOIN ProductTranslation as t on t.Id = o.Id and t.LanguageId = 4
) as d
WHERE Description like 'free'
OrderBy Name
```

To do this, the extension override `SqlExpressionFactory` like :

```cs
internal sealed class TranslationSqlExpressionFactory : SqlExpressionFactory
{
    public override SelectExpression Select(IEntityType entityType)
    {
        if (IsTranslatable(entityType))
        {
            var query = TranslationRawSql(entityType);
            var fromSqlExpression = new FromSqlExpression(entityType.GetTableMappings().Single().Table, query, Expression.Constant(new object[0]));
            return base.Select(entityType, fromSqlExpression);
        }
        return base.Select(entityType);
    }
}
```

Finaly, the original ISqlExpressionFactory` is replaced by this below :

```cs
internal sealed class TranslationOptionsExtension : IDbContextOptionsExtension
{

    public void ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISqlExpressionFactory, TranslationSqlExpressionFactory>();
    }
}
```

---

This work fine until EF Core 7. In this version, each provider has a own `ISqlExpressionFactory` :

- SqlServerSqlExpressionFactory
- SqliteSqlExpressionFactory
- ...

A solution is to create `TranslationSqlExpressionFactory` for each provider :

- TranslationSqlServerSqlExpressionFactory
- TranslationSqliteSqlExpressionFactory
- ...

Do you know other alternative? Maybe a service more adapted to that need?