# dotnet - Create a type at runtime that inherit of generic and override method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a base class `Base` and many implementation like `FinalA`, `FinalB`, ... :

```cs
public class Base
{
    public virtual string Foo() => "From Base";
}

public class RealA : Base
{
    public override string Foo() => $"From RealA, { base.Foo()}";
}

public class RealB : Base
{
    public override string Foo() => "From RealB, " + base.Foo();
}
```

I need to create a new type at runtime, that derived from `Base` or other type that derives from `Base`, like :

```cs
System.Type GetFinalType<T>() where T : Base
{
    // Return a type that inherit of T and override Foo to return "From final type, { base.Foo }"
}

System.Type finalType = GetFinalType<Base>();
Console.WriteLine(((Base)Activator.CreateInstance(finalType)).Foo());
// Display "From final type, From Base"

System.Type finalTypeA = GetFinalType<RealA>();
Console.WriteLine(((Base)Activator.CreateInstance(finalTypeA)).Foo());
// Display "From final type, From RealA, From Base"

System.Type finalTypeB = GetFinalType<RealB>();
Console.WriteLine(((Base)Activator.CreateInstance(finalTypeB)).Foo());
// Display "From final type, From RealB, From Base"
```

The dotnet target is the next .NET 8, then I will accept solution that use preview functionalities from .NET 8.

Comment: _"I need to create a new type at runtime"_ - I wonder why exactly, because it is rarely what you actually need (but there are some cases though). _" that use preview functionalities from .NET 8"_ -  do you have any particular feature in mind?

Comment: _"that inherit of generic"_ - there are no generics in the provided code...

Comment: @GuruStron It's to resolve this other [EF Core : Inject custom SqlExpressionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76911289/ef-core-inject-custom-sqlexpressionfactory).

Comment: I was planning to look at this one. Personally I think that there is an easier approach but I need some time to test it.

Comment: @GuruStron The generic type is in `GetFinalType<T>()`.

Comment: It is generic type parameter, there is no inheriting from generic type though. At least wording is not clear/correct in my opinion.

Comment: @GuruStron The created type return by `GetFinalType<T>()` inherit of T. If I misused some term, question editing are welcome.